# Run a test only when building package on my local machine

Tags: r, unit-testing, package, cran

Say I am developing an R package and have some tests that are executed with `R CMD check`.

I want some of those tests to only execute when I build the package locally on my machine and be skipped when the package is handled by CRAN.

One solution would be to comment-out those tests before uploading the package to CRAN, but this is error-prone and manual.

Is there some if statement or a setting I can add in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`skip_on_cran()` is what you need.

```r
test_that("skip example", {
  expect_equal(1, 1L)    # this expectation runs
  skip_on_cran()
  expect_equal(1, 2)     # this one skipped
  expect_equal(1, 3)     # this one is also skipped
})
```

---

## Edit

You're not using **testthat**. You can do:

```r
notOnCRAN <- function() {
  identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN"), "true")
}
```

and put your tests in `if(notOnCRAN()) { ...... }`.

---

## Edit

Nope... Maybe:

```r
notOnCRAN <- function() {
  !identical(Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_"), "true")
}
```

Comment: I was assuming you use **testthat**... is it the case?

Comment: No, just regular `./test/` folder with scripts that do `all.equal()` checks: [example](https://github.com/karoliskoncevicius/matrixTests/tree/master/tests)

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I looked at the code. See my edit, not sure it works.

Comment: Yeah I also looked at the code and same impression - not sure if this works. I wonder if `R CMD check --as-cran` sets this variable or not.

Comment: OK this will not work. "NOT_CRAN" is set by `devtools` so seems what they are doing is setting it for themselves and assuming that CRAN will not be running the tests with the help of `devtools`. More appropriate name for this function would be `skip_without_devtools()`.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Yep. Maybe [`_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_`](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-ints/Tools.html) ?

Comment: I found a duplicate on SO, so closed this question now. I think the solution by Dirk is great option.